# When I add a new class/id my html validator says it is a mistake and the class/id doesn't work

Tags: html, css

When I give for example to `<a\>\</a\>` a class `--\> \<a class="example"\>\</a\>` it says that it is an error and also when I try writing CSS, VSCode doesn't seem to find it;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>My lerning path</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .Munte {
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(255, 249, 78), rgb(127, 255, 185), rgb(127, 255, 185), rgb(127, 255, 185), cyan);
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 4px;
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 2.35rem;
      font-weight: 20;
    }
    
    .Blog {
      height: auto;
      width: auto;
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(66, 89, 219), rgb(211, 84, 237), rgb(255, 156, 26));
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 4px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: 20;
    }
    
    .Blog p {
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 60px;
      font-weight: 20;
      font-size: 1.7rem;
    }
    
    .Blog h2 {
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 30px;
      font-weight: 40;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    footer {
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      margin-top: 50px;
      padding-left: 26px;
    }
    
    footer h4 {
      padding-left: 240px;
      font-weight: 20;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Munte">
    <h1>My start</h1>
    <p>This is rudementary page that I made in 5min.</p>
    <p>Hope you have a great day.</p>
    <p>And I believe in my career as a full-stack developer</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Blog">
    <h1>Blog Posts:</h1>
    <section>
      <h2>Post Nr. I</h2>
      <p>I just learned a little more about the gradient that is used for HTML & CSS</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>I want to thank <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org">&copy;freecodecamp.org</a> for their amazing courses.</p>
    <h3 style="display: inline;">Contact Me:</h3>
    <h4 style="display: block;"><a href="https://github.com/teodorgolan">•GitHub</a></h4>
    <h4 style="display: block;"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/teodor-golan-59ab99299" class="ap">•LinkedIn</a></h4>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

W3C says that this code is valid, but when I try adding a class it says that those are errors and I cannot use it in CSS.

Can someone explain me why I can not add classes or ids.

I tried googling but I can not find anything related to this.

I really don't know what is causing this, or maybe I write the wrong syntax, I really do not know.

Comment: Can you show us the validation error you are given?

Answer (score -1):

I ran this code on my development server and it works fine. I added a class to the `<a></a>` tag and I added a style to it:

```css
.example {
    color: red;
}
```

I also added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`, which could be a reason for your code not working the way you want it to.

If none of these work, it is likely an error with whatever you use to test the HTML file. If there are other issues, please let me know and I can try my best to help fix your problem!

Here is the full code of what I added:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My learning path</title>
    <style>
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }

      .Munte {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        background: linear-gradient(
          180deg,
          rgb(255, 249, 78),
          rgb(127, 255, 185),
          rgb(127, 255, 185),
          rgb(127, 255, 185),
          cyan
        );
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 4px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 2.35rem;
        font-weight: 20;
      }

      .Blog {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        background: linear-gradient(
          180deg,
          rgb(66, 89, 219),
          rgb(211, 84, 237),
          rgb(255, 156, 26)
        );
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 4px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: 20;
      }

      .Blog p {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 60px;
        font-weight: 20;
        font-size: 1.7rem;
      }

      .Blog h2 {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 30px;
        font-weight: 40;
      }

      body {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      footer {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        margin-top: 50px;
        padding-left: 26px;
      }

      footer h4 {
        padding-left: 240px;
        font-weight: 20;
      }

      .example {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="Munte">
      <h1>My start</h1>
      <p>This is rudementary page that I made in 5min.</p>
      <p>Hope you have a great day.</p>
      <p>And I believe in my career as a full-stack developer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Blog">
      <h1>Blog Posts:</h1>
      <section>
        <h2>Post Nr. I</h2>
        <p>
          I just learned a little more about the gradient that is used for HTML
          & CSS
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p>
        I want to thank
        <a class="example" href="https://www.freecodecamp.org"
          >&copy;freecodecamp.org</a
        >
        for their amazing courses.
      </p>
      <h3 style="display: inline">Contact Me:</h3>
      <h4 style="display: block">
        <a href="https://github.com/teodorgolan">•GitHub</a>
      </h4>
      <h4 style="display: block">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/teodor-golan-59ab99299" class="ap"
          >•LinkedIn</a
        >
      </h4>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry but it still doen't work, I still get errors: ,,Do not use empty rulesets,,-this is when I tried to make a new class; ,,Trailing slash on void elements has no effect and interacts badly with unquoted attribute values."- and this is for the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`; And I use VScode to write the lines and VScode's W3C Validator to validate my HTML; And btw I tried adding a new class to your code and it was the same result.

Comment: What browser are you using to view the preview?